# What are the benefits to scheduling an Uber Ride ahead of time?

Tags: taxis, mobile-apps, uber

What additional benefits are there to scheduling your ride ahead of time that you don't get from just calling an Uber when you are ready?

- Is it basically just for "I might be busy, don't let me forget to call an Uber", or
- Are there additional benefits, such as you are more likely to be able to get an Uber at your scheduled time if otherwise the app may have shown "No Drivers available"?

Comment: While this is not a good question for the site since it's primarily opinion based but one example may be places where Uber may not be available during all ours of the day.  Which is what happened to me one day in Florida where at 4 am there was no Uber to be had.

Comment: I've used it to schedule a ride to the airport in the wee hours of the morning. Very useful.

Comment: @Karlson I trimmed out all the personal stuff to focus on the main question, which I think was lost in the original post. Your comment sounds exactly like what I'm looking for, if I understand you correctly. Are you saying that if you had not scheduled your ride, you are confident the Uber app would have said "No Drivers available" for your location at that time and you wouldn't have been able to use Uber?

Comment: @MarkMayo Was it useful because you didn't have to worry about calling the Uber when you may have been trying to get ready for your flight/sleepy?

Comment: @tehDorf more because public transport shuts down in Sydney at that time :/

Answer (score 6):

At this point, I think the benefit of scheduling an Uber ride ahead of time is basically, as you said, "I might be busy, don't let me forget to call an Uber." It doesn't look like Uber sends out any kind of special requests to drivers when you schedule ahead of time; they just send out the usual request automatically when your requested time approaches. Thus, scheduling ahead of time does not guarantee a ride.
*Source*: [Uber help page](https://help.uber.com/h/63165ec1-0910-409e-972f-0b8d8df1a605)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm assuming as well. I'm hoping for a more concrete answer, though.